# Status List Indicators for Project Task List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having issues setting up a status indicator for a Project Task List. I can set indicators just fine for Task lists, but not the Project Task list. Any ideas if the Project Task list is not compatible with the Status Indicator List?